# MongoDB: mongoexport produces blank json and error message

Tags: json, macos, mongodb

I have a MongoDB dbs named test with a collection named items. It has one item. I'm currently learning how to export a copy of the collections, but I get an error message: **Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers** and a blank .json document. Below is my command for mongoexport in my terminal (using a Mac):

```
mongoexport --db test --collection items --authenticationDatabase admin --out test.json
```

How would I fix this so that I get the data from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the host parameter:

```
mongoexport --host=127.0.0.1 --db test --collection items --authenticationDatabase admin --out test.json
```